# Inacurate using SURF or ORB algorithm with openCv in Android

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface, image-recognition

I'm new in OpenCv, so I'm going to try explain my problem. (Sorry for my poor English)

**Objective**

An Android application with OpenCv that, with an amount of images saved or downloaded(it doesn't matter where it come from), get the application recognize every image in the frame of the camera and draw a rectangle around the image found in that frame.

[Something like this example](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/receipt-outlined.jpg) but in my case, if there is more than one 'image match', it would be drawn as well all of them on the same frame or equivalent.

**Problem**

I was reading many posts and doing the opencv samples I got it works in a exe but when a try to pass it to an Android app it doesn't work properly.

[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283207/what-is-the-best-suited-method-for-detecting-images-using-android-device-for-mar),[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655067/recognizing-an-image-from-a-list-with-opencv-sift-using-the-flann-matching),[Post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058435/what-to-do-with-orb-feature-matches)..

I tried with SURF (It`s compiled the nonfree library in Android), ORB  and and FLANN matcher algorithms but I just get different inaccurate lines for every directions or just points.

My try:

**Java Activity based on sample 2 of Opencv**

```
package org.opencv.jc.tct;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
public class Tutorial2Activity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
private static final String    TAG = "TCT";


private static final int       CORRECT            = 0;
private static final int       FAILED             = 1;

private Mat                    mRgba;
private Mat                    mIntermediateMat;
private Mat                    mGray;
private int                    res = -1;
private CameraBridgeViewBase   mOpenCvCameraView;

private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
                System.loadLibrary("mixed_sample");
                //Image_Interface.imageBase(); //TODO Carga los cuadros descargados de internet.
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

public Tutorial2Activity() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial2_surface_view);

    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial2_activity_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            res = ImageInterface.imageBase();
            if(res == CORRECT)
                ImageInterface.NativeDataTest();
        }
    });

    th.start();

}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_11, this, mLoaderCallback);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);

    mGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);

}

public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mRgba.release();
    mGray.release();

}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();
    if(res == CORRECT){
        ImageInterface.imageFrame(mGray.getNativeObjAddr(), mRgba.getNativeObjAddr());
    }else if(res == FAILED){
        Log.i(TAG, "Imagenes base no está lista");
    }
    return mGray;
}


}
```

**Intermediate class**

```
package org.opencv.jc.tct;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class ImageInterface {
private static final String    TAG = "TCT";
private static long[]          imaArray;

public static int imageBase(){
    int nativeRes = -1;
    getBitmapFromURL();
    if(imaArray.length > 0 && imaArray != null){     
     nativeRes = ProcessImagesBase(imaArray);
    }

    return nativeRes;
}

public static void imageFrame(long matAddrGr, long matAddrRgba){
    ProcessImageFrame( matAddrGr, matAddrRgba);
}

public static void NativeDataTest(){
    TestData();
}


// download data from internet //
private static void getBitmapFromURL() {

    String[] imageUrl = {"http://s7.postimg.org/3yz6bb87f/libro2.jpg"};
    imaArray = new long[imageUrl.length];

    for(int i=0; i<imageUrl.length; i++){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl[i]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)     url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            if(myBitmap != null){
                Mat mat = new Mat();
                Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap, mat);
                if(!mat.empty()){
                    mat.convertTo(mat, CvType.CV_8UC1);
                    Log.i("ImageInterface", "Image downloaded type: "+mat.type());
                }else
                    Log.i("ImageInterface", "Mat: "+ i + " Vacias");
                imaArray[i] = mat.getNativeObjAddr();
                Log.i("ImageInterface", "BITMAP: "+ i + "LLENO");
            }else
                Log.i("ImageInterface", "BITMAP VACIO");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }
    } 
    Log.i("ImageInterface", "Array de direcciones: "+imaArray.length);
}

//Get App Data Folder in Android
public File getDataFolder(Context context) {
    File dataDir = null;
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            dataDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "files");
            if(!dataDir.isDirectory()) {
                dataDir.mkdirs();
            }
        }

        if(!dataDir.isDirectory()) {
            dataDir = context.getFilesDir();
        }

    return dataDir;
}


  public void writeDataFolder(Context context){

    String[] pathList = {"http://localhost/libro1.jpg",
                         "http://localhost/libro2.jpg"};

    URL wallpaperURL = null;
    for(int i=0; i < pathList.length;i++){
        try {
            wallpaperURL = new URL(pathList[i]);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            URLConnection connection = wallpaperURL.openConnection();
            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(wallpaperURL.openStream(), 10240);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        File cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, "localFileName.jpg");
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        int dataSize;
               try {
                while ((dataSize = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {              
                       outputStream.write(buffer, 0, dataSize);
                   }

                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
private native static int ProcessImagesBase(long[] arrayImage); 
private native static void ProcessImageFrame(long matAddrGr, long matAddrRgba);
private native static void TestData();
}
```

**C++ JNI**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_opencv_jc_tct_ImageInterface_ProcessImagesBase(JNIEnv* env, jobject,jlongArray traindataaddr);
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_jc_tct_ImageInterface_ProcessImageFrame(JNIEnv*,
            jobject, jlong addrGray, jlong addrRgba);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_jc_tct_ImageInterface_TestData(JNIEnv*,jobject);

void trainDetector();

void trainExtractor();

void trainMatches(Mat& descriptors_scene,vector<vector<vector<DMatch> > >& matches);

void getGoodMatches(vector<vector<vector<DMatch> > >& matches, vector<vector<DMatch> >& tr_good_matches);

void perspectiveScene(vector<vector<DMatch> >& tr_good_matches, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints_scene, Mat& img_scene);

const bool testing = false;
const int CORRECT  = 0;
const int FAIL     = 1;

static vector<vector<KeyPoint> > train_keypoints;
static vector<Mat> train_descriptors;
static vector<Mat> trainImages;

OrbFeatureDetector detector(400);
OrbDescriptorExtractor extractor;
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_opencv_jc_tct_ImageInterface_ProcessImagesBase(JNIEnv* env,jobject, jlongArray traindataaddr) {

    jint result = -1;

    jsize a_len = env->GetArrayLength(traindataaddr);
    jlong *traindata = env->GetLongArrayElements(traindataaddr,0);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int k=0;k<a_len;k++)
    {
        Mat & newimage=*(Mat*)traindata[k];
        trainImages.push_back(newimage);
    }
    // do the required manipulation on the images;
    env->ReleaseLongArrayElements(traindataaddr,traindata,0);


    trainDetector();
    trainExtractor();

    if (!train_keypoints.empty()){
        LOGI("Created Keypoints!!!");
        result = CORRECT;
    }
    else{
        LOGE("Error creating the keypoints");
        result = FAIL;
    }
    return result;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_jc_tct_ImageInterface_ProcessImageFrame(JNIEnv*,
        jobject, jlong addrGray, jlong addrRgba) {

    Mat& img_scene = *(Mat*) addrGray;
    Mat& mRgb = *(Mat*) addrRgba;

    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_scene;
    detector.detect(img_scene, keypoints_scene);

    Mat descriptors_scene;
    extractor.compute(img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene);

    //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
    if(!descriptors_scene.empty()){
        vector<vector<vector<DMatch> > > matches;
        trainMatches(descriptors_scene, matches);

        if(!matches.empty()){
            LOGI("Matches [0]: %d",matches[0].size());
            vector<vector<DMatch> > tr_good_matches;
            getGoodMatches( matches, tr_good_matches);

            if(!tr_good_matches.empty()){
                LOGI("GOOD MATCHES FRAME size %d",tr_good_matches[0].size());
                perspectiveScene(tr_good_matches, keypoints_scene, img_scene);
            }else{
                LOGE("MATCHES FRAME emtpy!");
            }
        }else
            LOGE("MATCHES FRAME empty!");
    }else{
        LOGE("MAT Descriptor FRAME empty");
    }


    // Mat img_matches;
    // drawMatches( img_object, keypoints_object, img_scene, keypoints_scene,
    //              good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
    //              vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );


 }

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_jc_tct_ImageInterface_TestData(JNIEnv*,jobject){

    if(!trainImages.empty())
        LOGI("TEST Trainimages %d",trainImages.size());
    else
        LOGI("TEST TrainImages empty");

}

void trainDetector() {
    LOGI("Train Detector");
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < trainImages.size(); i++) {

        vector<KeyPoint> obj_kp;
        detector.detect(trainImages[i], obj_kp);

        if (!obj_kp.empty()) {
            train_keypoints.push_back(obj_kp);

        } else if (testing) {
            LOGE("Error: There are not keypoints. Func: trainDetector");
        }
    }

    LOGI("Trainimages size %d ",trainImages.size());
}

void trainExtractor() {

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < trainImages.size(); i++) {

        Mat* obj_desc = new Mat();
        extractor.compute(trainImages[i], train_keypoints[i], *obj_desc);

        if (!(*obj_desc).empty()) {

            train_descriptors.push_back(*obj_desc);

        } else if (testing) {
            LOGI("Error: Problem with descriptors. Func: trainExtractor");
        }
    }

    LOGE("Train descriptors: %d",train_descriptors.size());
}

void getGoodMatches(vector<vector<vector<DMatch> > >& matches,vector<vector<DMatch> >& tr_good_matches) {
    //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
    for (int i = 0; i < train_descriptors.size(); i++) {
        double max_dist = 0;
        double min_dist = 100;
        Mat obj_desc = train_descriptors[i];
        vector<DMatch> gm;

        for (int j = 0; j < min(obj_desc.rows - 1, (int) matches[i].size());j++) {
            if (matches[i][j][0].distance <  matches[i][j][1].distance
                    && ((int) matches[i][j].size() <= 2
                            && (int) matches[i][j].size() > 0)) {
                gm.push_back(matches[i][j][0]);
            }
        }

        tr_good_matches.push_back(gm);
    }
}

void perspectiveScene(vector<vector<DMatch> >& tr_good_matches, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints_scene, Mat& img_scene) {
    LOGI("PERS FUNCTION");
    //-- Localize the object
    std::vector<Point2f> obj;
    std::vector<Point2f> scene;
    int R, G, B;
    for (int i = 0; i < tr_good_matches.size(); i++) {
        LOGI("PF: For train size[%d]: %d",i,tr_good_matches[i].size());
        obj.clear();
        scene.clear();
        if (tr_good_matches[i].size() >= 4) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tr_good_matches[i].size(); j++) {
                //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
                obj.push_back(train_keypoints[i][tr_good_matches[i][j].queryIdx].pt);
                scene.push_back(keypoints_scene[tr_good_matches[i][j].trainIdx].pt);
            }
            LOGI("Obj size: %d, scene size: %d",obj.size(),scene.size());
            if (!obj.empty() && !scene.empty()) {
                LOGI("OBJ size: %d, scene size: %d",obj.size(),scene.size());

                Mat H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);

                //-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
                vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
                obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0, 0);
                obj_corners[1] = cvPoint(trainImages[i].cols, 0);
                obj_corners[2] = cvPoint(trainImages[i].cols,
                        trainImages[i].rows);
                obj_corners[3] = cvPoint(0, trainImages[i].rows);
                vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);

                perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);
                //getPerspectiveTransform(obj_corners,scene_corners);
                R = rand() % 256;
                G = rand() % 256;
                B = rand() % 256;

                //-- Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene - image_2 )
                line(img_scene, scene_corners[0], scene_corners[1],
                        Scalar(R, G, B), 4);
                line(img_scene, scene_corners[1], scene_corners[2],
                        Scalar(R, G, B), 4);
                line(img_scene, scene_corners[2], scene_corners[3],
                        Scalar(R, G, B), 4);
                line(img_scene, scene_corners[3], scene_corners[0],
                        Scalar(R, G, B), 4);

            } else{
                LOGE("Error: Problem with goodmatches. Func: perspectiveScene.");
            }
        }
    }
}

void trainMatches( Mat& descriptors_scene, vector<vector<vector<DMatch> > >& matches) {

    for (int i = 0; i < train_descriptors.size(); i++) {
        vector<vector<DMatch> > obj_matches;
        Mat desc = train_descriptors[i];

        if(desc.type() != CV_32F){
            desc.convertTo(desc,CV_32F);
        }

        if(descriptors_scene.type() != CV_32F){
            descriptors_scene.convertTo(descriptors_scene,CV_32F);
        }

        matcher.knnMatch(desc, descriptors_scene, obj_matches, 2);

        if (!obj_matches.empty()) {
            matches.push_back(obj_matches);

        } else if (testing) {
            LOGE("Error: Problem with matches. Func: trainMatches");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Could you say me what is it wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried mutiobject detection on android using Surf Detector, Descriptor Extractor and flannbased Matcher. I used Jni, ever thing is working fine but the frame rate is less than 0.5. I don't know what to do to increase frame rate?

I placed some Images in "detect" folder in Sdcard. In the menu when I press Load, then images in "detect" folder are loaded and trainDescriptors are found in seperate Thread.

After Images are loaded then press Start in menu to start detecting objects.

**processframe.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<jni.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"



using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

vector<Mat> trainImages;
Ptr<FeatureDetector> featureDetector=FeatureDetector::create("SIFT" );
 Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> descriptorExtractor=DescriptorExtractor::create("SIFT");
Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> descriptorMatcher=DescriptorMatcher::create("FlannBased");//new BFMatcher(NORM_HAMMING,true);//
vector<vector<KeyPoint> > trainKeypoints;
vector<Mat> trainDescriptors;
vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);
vector<Point2f> obj_corner(4);
vector<KeyPoint> queryKeypoints;
Mat queryDescriptors ;
vector<vector<DMatch> > matches;
vector<DMatch > good_matches;
int imagefound=-1;
Mat H;
char buffer[50];

int reprojectionThreshold=3;

bool refineMatchesWithHomography(const vector<KeyPoint>& querykeypoints,const vector<vector<KeyPoint> >& trainkeypoints, const vector<Mat> &trainimages,
                                           float reprojectionthreshold,vector<DMatch>& goodmatches,int &imagefound, Mat& Homo)
{

   vector<Point2f> src;
    vector<Point2f> dst;

   //cout<<good_matches.size()<<"\n";
   if (goodmatches.size() < 8)
   {
     imagefound=-1;
      return false;
   }


    for( int i=0;i<goodmatches.size();i++)
    {
        DMatch imatch = goodmatches[i];
        src.push_back(trainkeypoints[imatch.imgIdx][imatch.trainIdx].pt);
        dst.push_back(querykeypoints[imatch.queryIdx].pt);
        for(int j=0;j<trainimages.size();j++)
        {
            if(goodmatches[j].imgIdx==j)
            {
                imagefound=j;

            }
         }
     }
       vector<unsigned char> maskmatch(src.size());
       Homo = findHomography( src,dst , CV_RANSAC,reprojectionthreshold,maskmatch);

       vector<DMatch> inliers;
       for (size_t i=0; i<maskmatch.size(); i++)
       {
       if (maskmatch[i])
       inliers.push_back(goodmatches[i]);
      }
      goodmatches.swap(inliers);

 return goodmatches.size() >8;
 }

 extern "C" {

 JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_cameraobjectdetection_loadImages_NativesendPaths(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jobjectArray stringArray);
 JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_cameraobjectdetection_NativeFrameProcessor_process(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jlong mrgba, jlong mprocessed);

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_cameraobjectdetection_loadImages_NativesendPaths(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jobjectArray stringArray) 
{
int stringCount = env->GetArrayLength(stringArray);
for (int i = 0; i<stringCount; i++) {
        jstring string = (jstring) env->GetObjectArrayElement(stringArray, i);
        const char *rawstring = env->GetStringUTFChars(string,0);
        std::string s(rawstring);
        Mat img=imread(s);
         cvtColor(img,img, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        trainImages.push_back(img);
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(string,rawstring);
    }
if(trainImages.empty()==0)
{

 featureDetector->detect(trainImages,trainKeypoints);
 descriptorExtractor->compute( trainImages, trainKeypoints, trainDescriptors );
 descriptorMatcher->add( trainDescriptors );
 descriptorMatcher->train();
}
else
{
    return false;
}

return true;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_cameraobjectdetection_NativeFrameProcessor_process(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jlong mrgba, jlong mprocessed)
{
Mat& mRgb = *(Mat*)mrgba;
 Mat& mProcess = *(Mat*)mprocessed;


 cvtColor(mRgb,mRgb, CV_BGR2GRAY);

 mProcess =mRgb;
vector<KeyPoint> queryKeypoints;
    featureDetector->detect(mRgb,queryKeypoints);

    Mat queryDescriptors ;
    descriptorExtractor->compute(mRgb,queryKeypoints,queryDescriptors);

   vector<vector<DMatch> > matches;
   descriptorMatcher->knnMatch(queryDescriptors,matches,2);
     vector<DMatch > good_matches;


     for(int i = 0; i < min(queryDescriptors.rows-1,(int) matches.size  ()); i++)
        {
            if((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][1].distance)) && ((int) matches[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches[i].size()>0))
            {
                good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
            }
        }

     bool foundhomography= refineMatchesWithHomography(queryKeypoints,trainKeypoints,trainImages,reprojectionThreshold,good_matches,imagefound,H);

           if(foundhomography)
           {

            if (good_matches.size()>8&&imagefound!=-1)
            {
                obj_corner[0] = cvPoint(0,0);
                obj_corner[1] = cvPoint(  trainImages[imagefound].cols, 0 );
                obj_corner[2] = cvPoint( trainImages[imagefound].cols, trainImages[imagefound].rows );
                obj_corner[3] = cvPoint( 0, trainImages[imagefound].rows );

                 perspectiveTransform(obj_corner , scene_corners, H);


                 sprintf(buffer,"image is: %d",imagefound);
                 putText(mProcess,buffer, Point(10,20), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, Scalar(0, 255, 255));
                 //obj_corner.clear();



                 line( mProcess, scene_corners[0], scene_corners[1] , Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );
                 line( mProcess, scene_corners[1] , scene_corners[2] , Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
                 line(mProcess, scene_corners[2] , scene_corners[3] , Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
                 line(mProcess, scene_corners[3] , scene_corners[0] , Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
            }
          }

   }
 }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.cameraobjectdetection;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {

Zoomcameraview zoomcameraview;
loadImages loadimages;
boolean start;
NativeFrameProcessor nativeframeprocessor;
Mat mRgba;
Mat mProcessed;
boolean started=false;

static 
{
 try
    { 
    // Load necessary libraries.
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
    System.loadLibrary("nonfree");

    }
 catch( UnsatisfiedLinkError e )
    {
    System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);        
    }
}

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                System.loadLibrary("process");
                zoomcameraview.enableFpsMeter();
                zoomcameraview.enableView();
                nativeframeprocessor=new NativeFrameProcessor();
                break;
            default:
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
                break;
        }
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    zoomcameraview = (Zoomcameraview)findViewById(R.id.ZoomCameraView);
    zoomcameraview.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    zoomcameraview.setZoomControl((SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.CameraZoomControls));
    zoomcameraview.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    loadimages=new loadImages(this);



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
    case R.id.load:
        loadimages.execute();

        break;
    case R.id.start:
        start=true;
        break;


    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (zoomcameraview!= null)
        zoomcameraview.disableView();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (zoomcameraview != null)
        zoomcameraview.disableView();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this,mLoaderCallback );
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mRgba = new Mat();
    mProcessed= new Mat();


}
@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mRgba=inputFrame.rgba();
    if(!start)
    {
      nativeframeprocessor.noprocessFrame(mRgba, mProcessed);

    }
    else if(start)
    {
    nativeframeprocessor.processFrame(mRgba, mProcessed);
    }
  return mProcessed;

 }
}
```

**loadImages.java**

```
package com.example.cameraobjectdetection;
import java.io.File;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast; 
public class loadImages  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

File[] files;
Context context;
String[] paths;
boolean nativesent;
public loadImages(Context _context)
{
    context=_context;

    String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/detect";

    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
     files = targetDirector.listFiles();
     paths=new String[files.length];

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    for (File file : files){
        Log.d("images",file.getAbsolutePath());
        paths[i]=file.getAbsolutePath();
        i++;

    } 

    nativesent=NativesendPaths(paths);
     Log.d("images pathsent",String.valueOf(nativesent));

    return null;
}

@Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      Log.d("images","loaded");
      if(nativesent)
        Toast.makeText(context,"Loaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }


 public native boolean NativesendPaths(String[] paths);

 }
```

**NativeFrameProcessor.java**

```
package com.example.cameraobjectdetection;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import android.util.Log;
public class NativeFrameProcessor 
{

public NativeFrameProcessor()
{

}
public void processFrame( Mat mRgba, Mat mProcessed)
{

  int image=process(mRgba.getNativeObjAddr(), mProcessed.getNativeObjAddr());   
    if(image!=-1)
    {
        Log.d("Image found","Image is:"+String.valueOf(image));
    }


}


public void noprocessFrame(Mat mRgba, Mat mProcessed)
{
    mRgba.copyTo(mProcessed);   
}

 public native int process(long matAddrRgba, long matAddrGray);

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About the rate of frame I was reading that SURF is a expensive algorith although high effective, maybe is due to. I'm going to try it as soon as I can! :)

Comment: I am trying to use Threads in order to increase the frame rate, but getting error.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424805/android-opencv-threading

Comment: I don't know if you get solve the problem, I had yesterday a similar problem and it was due to the image had not the same type (CV_U8C1...) or you are trying convert a empty Mat with cvtColor..

Comment: thanks for reply, problem was not yet solved. I will check it. Are you using threads for opencv on android?